# Debug php using VS Code: Unable to attach to browser

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, xdebug

I have installed xdebug following the instructions from here: http://xdebug.org/wizard

[image]

I have also installed Debugger for Chrome extension

[image]

Now I choose my index.php file and start the debugger, but I get the following error:

[image]

This is the content of lunch.json

[image]

This is the config that I have added to php.ini

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
```

### Update:

I have added `xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log` to php.ini and this is the error that I get:

```
[3569] I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
[3569] W: Creating socket for 'localhost:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[3569] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
```

Comment: Make the `xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log` setting and see what it shows.

Comment: @Derick: thanks for your help, I have added the log message.

Comment: Your log shows that VS Code is not listening. You need to configure it like this: https://www.codewall.co.uk/debug-php-in-vscode-with-xdebug/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [this document](https://www.codewall.co.uk/debug-php-in-vscode-with-xdebug/) that @Derick provided in the comment. I changed *lunch.json* to the following and it started working:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000,
            "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/php.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```